# Why the rate of Z boson decays produce 3 generations of matter?

Tags: matter, bosons, electroweak

I read a tons of article about Z boson, I know it is a carrier of weak force similar to photon except it is much much more massive than an electron and it is extremely short lived. Sadly almost all the content excluding abstract, table of contents and references contain mathematics and graphs, I just want to know why Z boson can have 3 different rate of decays and why are they groups into 3 generations of matter?

Comment: see the answer  here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/365519/could-neutrinos-have-more-than-3-flavors/365527#365527 . The generations exist and are of low enough mass for Z to decay to. All partial decay rates are different, one can add them up for each generation depending on the argument of the specific study. One would then have three partial rates.

Comment: @annav: actually I already tried googling every keywords I can find, I'm looking for simpler explanation preferably with illustrations like most astronomy papers.

Comment: @annav: for instance I know that z boson has a 20% chance(partial widths) to decay into 2 neutrinos and somehow it is mathematically proven, this decay is consider the last of the 3 generations. I won't ask for help to break down the math just the concept and maybe with illustrations :)

Comment: One cannot do physics with illustrations. One needs mathematics. The data are fitted with group theoretical models, and this explains what you are asking , but to understand the symmetries you need the mathematics.